# Wait subprocess until it outputs a certain line

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to execute a command line as a subprocess in the background.

So, I did it with following code:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen('command line', shell=True)
```

However, I should wait for the subprocess until it is ready and outputs 'Done'. And then I want to leave the subprocess running and run next line of my Python code.

How can I watch the standard output of the subprocess and go to next line if it prints a certain line?

Please help!
Thanks.

Comment: Look up the pexpect library on PyPI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Zondo's advice, I solved my own question with a library called `pexpect`.

It is really simple! If you want to execute a command and wait until it prints **'Done'**, then you can just do it like this:

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn('<command that you want>')
child.expect('Done')
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `subprocess.run` with `check=True`.

> **Python » Documentation** [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)
>       subprocess.run(args, *, stdin=None, input=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False, timeout=None, check=False, encoding=None, errors=None)
>
> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return a CompletedProcess instance.